# Phonegap Build Repository plugins not accessible

Tags: repository, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap, phonegap-pushplugin

I've an app I did in Phonegap more than an year ago and I need to change some things. But when I went to compile I received the following message:

> This app uses plugins from the PhoneGap Build repository. These
>   plugins won't be accessible after Nov 15th, 2016

I found that I needed to change all the references of the plugins to Phonegap's repository .

For example:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" />
```

for

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.statusbar" source="npm" />
```

That one was easy cause I found it in npmjs.com and it clear in the documentation:

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-statusbar

But there're several others that I cannot find or the documentation in npmjs is not clear to where I've to point:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" />
<gap:plugin name="com.oauthio.plugins.oauthio"  />
<gap:plugin name="com.ionic.keyboard" />
<gap:plugin name="hu.dpal.phonegap.plugins.uniquedeviceid" version="1.2.0" />   
<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" version="4.3.8" />   
<gap:plugin name="com.virtualartifacts.webintent" version="1.0.0" />
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" >
```

Is there any place where I can find these plugins and for the ones that are in the npmjs and the documentation doesn't say nothing about, know how to point to them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Here you can get the list of all plugins.**

https://build.phonegap.com/plugins

after updating phonegap cli 7+. Many cordova plugins are not working.But in that case we can use versioning.like this

These are the some working plugins

```
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="1.3.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="4.3.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="1.6.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="2.4.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="1.5.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="1.3.1" />
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.1.0" />

  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="2.4.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.7" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="2.2.1" />
```